# tar xvfz and -xvfc both didn't worked in Cygwin on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, tar

I tried tar with xvfz and -xvfc both didn't work in Cygwin on Windows.

```
$ tar xvfz sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz
tar (child): sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Here cmd tar with '-'

```
$ tar -xvfz sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz
tar: z: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Question : 1 . How does tar works with - or without _ ?

Please suggest to execute tar -xvfz sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz.

Comment: `tar xvfz sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz` seems to be correct. What displays `ls -l ./sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz` ?

Comment: yes, @Amessihel. $ ls -l | grep 'sshpass'
-rw-r--r--   1 Santosh.Maddela Users   98362 Aug  7  2011 sshpass-1.05.tar.gz

Comment: When combining 'short' options **(hyphen and single letter) 'f' must be last**: `tar -xzvf sshpass-1.0.5.tar.gz`. For 'old-style' options (no hyphen) the order within the clump doesn't matter. See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Short-Options.html#SEC37 Also your text says 'xvfc' but your code doesn't; 'x' and 'c' together (in either format) would be an error. And your `ls` shows `1.05` but you gave `1.0.5` in the commands; those are not the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085, got it now. `$ tar xvfz sshpass-1.05.tar.gz
sshpass-1.05/
sshpass-1.05/COPYING
sshpass-1.05/AUTHORS
sshpass-1.05/aclocal.m4
sshpass-1.05/INSTALL
sshpass-1.05/Makefile.am
sshpass-1.05/configure.ac
sshpass-1.05/install-sh
sshpass-1.05/Makefile.in
sshpass-1.05/sshpass.1
sshpass-1.05/configure
sshpass-1.05/depcomp
sshpass-1.05/README
sshpass-1.05/NEWS
sshpass-1.05/config.h.in
sshpass-1.05/missing
sshpass-1.05/main.c
sshpass-1.05/ChangeLog`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085 for your quick suggestion. Worked it without `-`

```
$ tar xvfz sshpass-1.05.tar.gz
sshpass-1.05/
sshpass-1.05/COPYING
sshpass-1.05/AUTHORS
sshpass-1.05/aclocal.m4
sshpass-1.05/INSTALL
sshpass-1.05/Makefile.am
sshpass-1.05/configure.ac
sshpass-1.05/install-sh
sshpass-1.05/Makefile.in
sshpass-1.05/sshpass.1
sshpass-1.05/configure
sshpass-1.05/depcomp
sshpass-1.05/README
sshpass-1.05/NEWS
sshpass-1.05/config.h.in
sshpass-1.05/missing
sshpass-1.05/main.c
sshpass-1.05/ChangeLog
```